# Can we have a generic wait method using ExpectedConditions and FluentWait in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Can we have a generic wait method... i.e. (1.wait for page load 2.Find the element 3.If not found refresh) and this goes on until the timeout of the fluentwait.

Comment: Of course you can, but have you looked into it yourself? First step is to set it up so that it just tries to find the element, then modify it so that if it doesn't find the element it just refreshes the page. Done.

Comment: I actually mean that three steps (1.wait for page load 2.Find the element 3.If not found refresh) go on multiple times so after the each refresh 1 and 2 run again.

Comment: OK, but what have you tried? You already know the classes you are dealing with. You are already familiar with finding elements. What's the issue here? What bits are you having trouble implementing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **WebdriverWait** for all the - ( 1.wait for page load 2.Find the element 3.If not found refresh )

```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 18); // Times Out after 18 Seconds
    PageUtil.refreshObject(driver, By.linkText("Element")); // refresh the Element
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Element"))); // wait till  Element is Enabled and Visible before Clicking on that Element

    /**
    *Pass the Control to that Element and Click on that Element (preferred in IE)
    *
    */
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Element"));
    element.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.CONTROL);
    element.click();
```

and Here is the **RefreshObject** method and **PageUtil** is the ClassName

```
public static WebElement refreshObject(WebDriver driver, By locator) {
        int counter = 0;

        try {
            counter = counter + 1;

            return driver.findElement(locator);
        }

        catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {

            return refreshObject(driver, locator);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have a special business case that requires this? If you don't you could just setup a implicit wait when you setup the driver object. In c# it would look something like:

```
myDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Many would say you should avoid implicit waits, but if you feel you need to go so far as to build a convenience method maybe the implicit wait is preferable.